# Git: squash merge with DAG

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-flow

I'm trying to use the [Gitflow Workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which I first met reading the [comparison of workflows at Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#gitflow-workflow). The main idea is that the development is done on the `develop` branch which contains all the modifications merged from feature branches, and after that we merge `develop` into `master`. This way feature branches never interact directly with our `master`.

What I would like to achieve is to have a **clean history** on the `master` branch with **only release commits**. So new commits should be added there only at version changes, but still I would want to see the **location of the merge** on the git tree. **Ordinary merges** usually take some of the commits with themselves and several commits appear in the history instead of just one new commit. **Squash merges** are able to solve the problem, they squash all the changes into one commit, however, they mess up my git tree, because squash merges don't end up with merge commits but ordinary commits which have only one parent not showing the connection between the two branches. *(This fools GitHub into thinking `master` is behind `develop` as well.)*

I want the history of `master` look like this:
[image: master]

The history of `develop`:
[image: develop]

Git tree:
[image: Git tree]

Is there a way to have squash merges with two parents creating a DAG (*Directed Acyclic Graph*) and connecting the two merged branches, meaning that my git tree would show me at which point was the `develop` (or the `release`) branch merged into `master`?

Answer (score 0):

Oridinary merge is just what you ask - squashed changes with the link to source branch. If you don't want to see the merged commits you only need to request for it. You can provide `--first-parent` argument to `git log` command and it will not output them:

```
git log --first-parent origin/master
```

PS: the feature is supported by bundled `gitk`, also by [sourcetree/macos](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1210) and [gitextensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2351). It is not by my knowledge implemented by public web services but for "bitbucket server" paid standalone server should be plugins which do this.

Comment: Yeah, but that way on GitHub or in any client with GUI still all the commits would appear, even those which I don't want to be there...

Comment: for UI clients there is some hope, see my PS